# SCCM 2007 PXE boot stuck at contacting server

Tags: sccm

We have an sccm 2007 server on windows 2008 r2 sp1. It has been handling pxe boot until yesterday. Clients get DHCP and is reffered to the correct server, but is gets stuck on contacting server.....

Server has been rebooted. Twice. WDS service is running. Tried deleting the computer accounts, alas it makes no difference.

Not able to find anything interesting in pxecontrol log. What could be the cause or where can i look further to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smspxe.log shows the clients as accepted and keeps repeating the same statement that the client is accepted, however the client will not boot.

Check to see if both the 32 and 64 bit boot images exist in SCCM. Even when only using the 32 bit boot image, SCCM requires the 64 bit image. Add the 64 bit image and distribute it to the DP's and yo can boot clients again.

Answer (score 0):

Did the networking team, or server team member, change any firewalls?  Are the correct UDP ports still open to support PXE?

Answer (score -1):

In our environment on the dell laptop the boot order has to be in the correct order for the pxe boot to working correctly. The hard drive has to be the first one on the list.

I would look at the desktop first and verify it is working correctly.